# How to send bulk SMS message with Twilio API from PHP

Tags: php, twilio, sms, twilio-api, twilio-php

As many other people have asked here, I am trying to figure how to send bulk SMS messages from PHP (Laravel) using the Twilio SMS API, and it is not simple (I am a paying customer and have a support ticket in for multiple days with no response, so I'm hoping for one here). My particular use case is for a private organization with ~2200 members, and we want to use SMS for things like event notifications/reminders and security/safety issues that require immediate notification.

In doing lots of searching, I keep finding references to the Notify service. However, that service has been [deprecated](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify). The [API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/php) and [PHP SDK](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php) show that you can only send a message to a single number at time, with a limit of one per second. When you have a need to get a safety message to a lot of people at once, for instance, that doesn't cut it.

I have a messaging service created with my purchased number in it, as that seems to be the way to send bulk messages. However, I have yet to figure out 1) what the correct code is for sending multiple SMS messages and 2) what other things I might be missing.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services ?

Comment: Were you an existing Notify customer? If so, you should still be able to use the service as we intend to deprecate the Notify product on April 25, 2024.

Comment: Twilio allows you to increase the number of messages per second and you could use a short code which allows 100 messages per second: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues & https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057082693-Can-I-increase-message-throughput-MPS-for-an-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-#:~:text=To%20request%20an%20MPS%20increase,associated%20with%20your%20Messaging%20Service

Comment: You should look at [Sociocs](https://www.sociocs.com), which allows sending Twilio bulk messages without writing any code.